# What package should I install for running a deployed .Net Core application?

Tags: .net

I'm building a .Net Core API which will be hosted on a Ubuntu based server. I'm installing the required packages I need on the server i.e. MySQL and Nginx, but I also need to install .Net Core of course for the application to run.

I found a [tutorial example](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/linuxproduction?tabs=aspnetcore2x) of how to setup and configure Nginx to work with the Kestrel server, but it entirely assumes you already have .Net Core installed on the machine it will be deployed on.

The .Net Core website only seems to instruct you to install the SDK, but this is for deployment, not development so it would make sense to install the .Net Core runtime instead, however when doing an `apt-cache search dotnet` to find the specific package name, I found `dotnet-hosting-2.0.0` listed too which is described with "Microsoft .NET Core 2.0.0 Linux Server Hosting".

To sum this up, my question is simply this. To host a .Net Core application, do you use the `dotnet-hosting` or the `dotnet-runtime` package for deployment of a .Net Core application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research, I have found that the `dotnet-hosting` package combines the `dotnet-runtime` and `aspnetcore-store` packages. Verified by [this Github comment](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/6516#issuecomment-334593515).

> The runtime and runtime store are packaged into "Linux Server Hosting" installers with the package name `dotnet-hosting-2.0.0`.

`aspnetcore-store` is now by [default a required dependency](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/6516#issuecomment-332577044) on published ASP.Net Core applications.

> By default, ASP.NET Apps are published with a dependency on the runtime store.

So to answer my question directly, `dotnet-hosting-x.x.x` should be installed when deploying an ASP.Net Core application. This will also eliminate the following error when `aspnetcore-store` is not installed along with the `dotnet-runtime` package.

`Error:
An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (APIproject.deps.json) was not found:
package: 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore', version: '2.1.1'
path: 'lib/netstandard1.6/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.dll'
This assembly was expected to be in the local runtime store as the application was published using the following target manifest files:
aspnetcore-store-2.0.0-linux-x64.xml;aspnetcore-store-2.0.0-osx-x64.xml;aspnetcore-store-2.0.0-win7-x64.xml;aspnetcore-store-2.0.0-win7-x86.xml`

I have tested the package myself on Ubuntu 16.04 with my application and it is working well.